# Irreducibility over $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is it the same thing?

1. Polynomial irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$.
2. Polynomial irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

We usually say a polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$. My question is: can we say that it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: Yes, a polynomial in $\;\mathbf Z[x,y]\;$ may be seen as polynomial in  $\;\mathbf Z[x][y]\;$  and, as such, may be or not, irreducible over $\;\mathbf Z[x]$. For a polynomial in $\;\mathbf Z[x]$, we say it is irreducible **in**  $\;\mathbf Z[x]$, not **over**   $\;\mathbf Z[x]$.

Comment: @Bernard : if you say so. can I say that $x^2-2$ factors over $\mathbb{R}[x]$ but not over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$  ?

Comment: @user1952009 No, you should say either "factors **in** $\mathbb{R}[x]$" *or* "factors **over** $\mathbb{R}$."